# How to assign allow all action `*/` to a specific role using code in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am creating new role using the below code.

```
use yii\rbac\PhpManager;
$r=new PhpManager;
$r->init();
$r->createRole("admin","Администратор"); 
$r->save();
```

I am assigning the above role to specific user.

```
$r->assign('1','admin');   //1 is user id
```

So how can i assign allow all action to the above role `admin` using php code.
Basically after run the migration i want to create a user as `admin` role and allow all the action's for this role.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the behavior `yii\filters\AccessControl` in your controllers, you could replace it with your own one in your `bootstrap.php`:

```
Yii::$classMap['yii\filters\AccessControl'] = @common/components/filters/AccessControl.php
```

Add the appropriate role in your AccessControl class, by copying the original AccessControl.php in your AccessControl.php and by extending the `init` function. At the end of init function just add your role:

```
public function init()
{
...
...
    $this->rules[] = [
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => ['admin'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslaM What about this approach?